# mysql fulltext exact phrase slow

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search

I'm using InnoDB Full text searching on a table.
I have created 400.000 dummy reports and created a fulltext.
The speed when searching one word is excellent.

```
SELECT count(*) from report where MATCH (reporttext) AGAINST ('dolor' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 0, 1000
1 row(s) returned   0.717 sec / 0.000 sec

count(*)
199629
```

When doing explain of the query :

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  report  fulltext    FTReportText    FTReportText    0   NULL    1   "Using where"
```

So far so good I would say, now when we run the following query:

```
SELECT count(*) from report where MATCH (reporttext) AGAINST ('"porttitor vulputate"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 0, 1000    1 row(s) returned
50.732 sec / 0.000 sec

count(*)
22947
```

Explain :

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
 1  SIMPLE  report  fulltext    FTReportText    FTReportText    0   NULL    1   "Using where"
```

As you can see for the 2nd query now the time is approx 50 seconds.
Is exact phrase search that expensive?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about the exact match query performance, but can you please try below query and see what is the performance?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   report 
WHERE  MATCH (reporttext) AGAINST ('porttitor vulputate' IN BOOLEAN MODE)   
  AND  reporttext LIKE '%porttitor vulputate%' LIMIT 0, 1000
```

Comment: Wow! this results in 6.80 seconds, and indeed the same amount of results.
I don't get this?

Comment: Fulltext indexes index tokens very well. But exact strings that contains multiple tokens should take longer to process. Possible Work Around is, filter using tokens first and then fetch the exact match using another and clause

Comment: Are there any negative side effects from this?
I mean, the results still get automatically ordered on relevance?
(I would expect so, since I'm using InnoDB Boolean Mode)

Comment: I don't think so, as full index is still used on reporttext column

Comment: Great answer! This will help me out in certain queries. Imagine how something so Obvious is so easy to miss. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you .. really time-saving.